# Posting to facebook page as page from php

Tags: php, facebook, post

I want to know if a php script from my website can post to facebook when a visitor posts a request on my website. If you have any suggestions, tutorials, useful articles or solution please post them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It can, using the Facebook API. For now it is unclear where you want to post what... Message on wall of user, message on own page, message on own wall, etc.

Comment: I want to post whatever the visitor posts on my website, to post my website fan page as page. The problem is that all the tutorials I found needed that I as admin to be logged in to facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a **Page Token** to post "as Page". You can create an **Extended Page Token** that is valid forever. With that Access Token, use the `/page-id/feed` endpoint to post to the Page.

That is the basic principle, information on how to deal with Access Tokens can be found here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

How to get an Extended Page Token in short:

- Authorize a user who is Admin of the page with the "manage_pages" and "publish_actions" permissions
- Extend the user token so it is valid for 60 days
- Use that Extended Token to call `/me/accounts` to get Extended Page Tokens for all your Pages

Comment: There aren't anymore tokens valid forever

Comment: that´s not true. app access tokens (not useful in your case) and extended page tokens ARE valid forever. if you don´t believe me, check out the first link i posted, it´s all in there ;)